# Can't start designed pyQt application

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, python-3.3, pyqt5

I have just designed my application inside pyQt Designer 5, generated my main.ui to main.py and my assets.qrc to assets_rc.py. No errors, when I now run main.py from my terminal nothing happends. Have I missed a step? Am I supposed to edit my main.py file now?

Cheers!

Python 3.3.0
pyQT 5

Comment: Don't run the py-File generated from the ui. Write a program that starts a QtApp which shows a QWidget (Window or whatever) with your ui. Just take a look at the generated py-Files and you'll see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This is for `PyQt4`, but should be the same for `PyQt5`.*

Let's say your ui is called "mainwindow.ui". Compile this with pyuic4 into "mainWindowUi.py" (or whatever, just stick to the name).

Now create a file "mainWindow.py" with more or less this content:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from mainWindowUi import Ui_MainWindow #same name as appears in mainWindowUi.py

class MainWindow (QtGui.QMainWindow): #Or wherever you are inheriting from
    def __init__ (self, parent = None):
        super (MainWindow, self).__init__ ()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow () #same name as appears in mainWindowUi.py
        self.ui.setupUi (self)

    #implement slots and signals and other funny things
```

Now create a file "program.py" with more or less this content:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3.3

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from mainWindow import MainWindow

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication (sys.argv)
    m = MainWindow ()
    m.show ()
    sys.exit (app.exec_ () )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main ()
```

Run the `program.py` file. This is more or less the skeleton of a Qt application.

Comment: Cheers, worked. Now I'm working on my problem I get with the original project. Output - https://gist.github.com/jackbillstrom/212eb13cbb3389ecad16

Comment: The message says it all. QDialogs don't have setCentralWidget. Maybe you want to inherit from another QtGui-class.