# first pyqt program fails

Tags: python, qt, signals-slots

I am experience with Qt4, but now try to get into the programming of Qt with python.

It works mainly but now I come across a basic python program I did not figure out:

> TypeError: setupSignalSlots() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, uic
from PyQt4 import QtCore

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('MainWindow.ui', self)
        self.show()

        self.setupSignalSlots(self)

    def setupSignalSlots(self):
        self.ui.actionQuit.clicked.connect(OnQuitMainWindow)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def OnQuitMainWindow():
        print('quit')
        QApplication.quit()
```

Besides that problem I wonder if the signal slot code is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several things wrong with the code you posted.

Firstly, the `OnQuitMainWindow` slot needs a `self` argument. However, you do not need to pass this argument explicitly as python will do it automatically. Secondly, when you connect to the slot, you need to access it via `self`. Finally, `quit` is not a static method of `QApplication`, so you need to call it via an instance (e.g. `qApp.quit()`).

(And one other nit-pick: in python (and Qt, for that matter), it goes against convention to start attribute names with a capital letter).

After making these corrections, your code should look like this:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, uic
from PyQt4 import QtCore

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('MainWindow.ui', self)
        self.show()

        self.setupSignalSlots()

    def setupSignalSlots(self):
        self.actionQuit.triggered.connect(self.onQuitMainWindow)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def onQuitMainWindow(self):
        print('quit')
        QtGui.qApp.quit()
```

**UPDATE**:

And one more thing I missed: the way you're using `uic.loadUi` means that the objects added in Qt Designer will end up as direct attributes of the instance of `MainWindow`. So it should be `self.actionQuit`, rather than `self.ui.actionQuit`. Also, since it appears that this object is a `QAction`, the signal should be `triggered`, rather than `clicked`.

Comment: Ok, I need to read more about pyhtons way of classes. The code here however fails because of `AttributeError: 'MainWindow' object has no attribute 'ui'`

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech. Apologies - I missed that one. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: How would the code look like such that the ui is saved in `self.ui`?

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech. Strictly speaking, you would have `MainWindow(object)`, get rid of the `super` call, and then do `self.ui = uic.loadUi('MainWindow.ui')`. This would mean _all_ methods of the main window and its attributes would need to be prepended with `self.ui` (for example, `self.ui.show()`, `self.ui.actionQuit`, etc). However, I have also seen people just do `self.ui = uic.loadUi('MainWindow.ui', self)` without the other changes - but I don't really see the point of this, since everything would then be accessible via both `self` _and_ `self.ui`.

Comment: Ok, I understand it so far. Nevertheless I wonder why most tutorials talk only about using `pyuic4` to generate a py file from the ui. And the whole doc page `http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/designer.html` does not provide any example using `loadUi`. In Qt/C++ loading of the generated ui code file is a must. With python this seems not to be necessary. But most examples dont compare the approaches.

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech. Personally, I much prefer the `pyuic` approach. It is more efficient than `loadUi` (at runtime), but in any case, I just like to have the python module to hand. It can be particularly helpful to review the code generated by `pyuic` when first learning PyQt. (PS: I did a simple comparison of the two approaches in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21540861/984421)).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass `self` to a method of a class; it is automatically done for you.  Just do `self.setupSignalSlots()`.